# Slicing strings in a data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like this (before).

```
BEFORE:
string
Oct 05 
190103
```

How can I make it look like this (after)?

```
AFTER:
string                                  the_date
Oct 05                                  181005
190103                                  190103
```

Comment: base on your description why last line is 1811 not 51811

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to match the last continuous sequence of numbers between the last space of a string and the last period of a string.  Use:

```
\s[^\s]+?(\d+)\.[^\.]+?$
```

---

#### `str.extract`

```
df['string'].str.extract(r'\s[^\s]+?(\d+)\.[^\.]+?$')
```

```
        0
0  181004
1  181004
2  181004
3  181106
4  181106
5  190102
6  190103
7   51811
```

---

As has been noted in the comments your last line should be `51811`, or else you are not using a consistent rule throughout your DataFrame.

---

***Regex Explanation***

```
\s                    # match a whitespace character
[^\s]+?               # match a non whitespace character between 1 and unlimited times, lazy
(                     # start of matching group 1
  \d+                 # match 1 or more digits          
)         
\.                    # match a period character
[^\.]+?               # match a non period character one to unlimited times, lazy
$                     # assert position at end of line
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54119901/9962315

or use code below, it also works fine with your data.

```
strToCheck = '10 30067    10224     1613788 Nov 07 01:55 USE4D181106.XBET'
the_date = ''

# step 1 - get the last substring with 'the_date' parameter
test = strToCheck.split(' ')[-1].split('.')[0]

# step 2 - loop test string and build right 'the_date' parameter 
for char in reversed(test):
    try:
        int(char)
        the_date = char+the_date
    except ValueError:
        break
print(the_date)
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple regex seems to work well:

```
/[A-Z]\d(\d+)\./
```

It will also take care of case where CAE51811 should output 1811 but not 51811.